# Is it faster to read a file on an NVMe using threads?

Tags: multithreading, filesystems, fread, drive, nvme

Assuming a file sitting on an NVMe drive is structured in a very standard way, e.g. a binary file filled with 8-byte integers: is it faster these days to read those integers into an array in parallel using threads?

I read that NVMe drives are very effective at concurrent, random access reading, but is it to such an extent that reading a file via 8 or so threads would be quicker than reading the file sequentially?

On a regular HDD or older SSD drives, reading non-sequentially would obviously be slower, given the bouncing reader head or whatever causes the bottleneck in the case of older SSD drives.  However, is this still the case for NVMe drives, or can we start reading files from NVMe disks in parallel and expect faster results?

Comment: This is very dependent of the precise NVMe storage device and the access pattern. For sequential read, the benefit of using multiple threads is generally small. For random access, it is generally quite big. For HDD, using multiple threads is nearly always a bad idea compared to an optimized read (it often make things much slower). For classical SSD, it depends a lot of the exact storage device (some behave really poorly while other can be fine). Note that the use of the SLC cache can impact the result of this question too so even the size of the file and the remaining space can matter.

Comment: Fortunately, there are benchmarks to test that and you can use them to get your answer ;) . For example, you can use CrystalDiskMark which is able to use multiple threads, different size of file, a variable queue size, and different access pattern in both read/write mode.

Comment: Note that asynchronous reads if often the key for good performance though multiple threads are sometimes needed to reach the maximum throughput on some platforms. Note that results are also dependent on the OS and the IO API used. On Linux, io_uring is very fast and 1 thread is often enough to reach a very good throughput, but it is low-level and quite complicated IMHO. On Windows there is IO completion ports (which AFAIK use multiple threads and often need that for good read performance on high-end NVMe devices).

Comment: Thank you!  Sadly I don't run Windows, so CrystalDiskMark wouldn't be much help to me here, nor do I own an NVMe drive personally… I was mostly asking for preliminary exploratory reasons, ahead of purchasing new disks.  Bleeding edge NVMes are expensive, so I want to know more about them.  E.g. reading a file from 2/3 separate disks simultaneously via threading (RAID-0 style storage) brings speed boosts, so I was mainly wondering if the architecture of NVMe drive could potentially bring any similar speed boosts when using multi-threading to read stripes of the file simultaneously into memory.

Comment: Regarding the benchmark, they are pretty common. For example, on Linux, there is for example KDiskMark which is very similar. As for the rest, the answer is simply : it depends. NVMe are technically massively parallel devices so often threads do not causes significant performance issues (besides making sequential accesses look more random). However, they may not help much if the software/firmware stacks are well designed and already benefit from the inherent data/task parallelism. A bad software stack might use locks so threads can be detrimental for performance (APIs & OS drivers).